# appwrite and flutter query using or operator

Tags: flutter, appwrite

what I want to do is list all the documents in a collection lets say users collection where the user is in management or his salary is more than 2000
how could I do it

I have tried using queries yet appwrite creates the queries as an and operation

Answer (score 0):

OR logic is unsupported at the moment. You will have to make multiple API requests for each OR condition and combine the data client-side.

FYI, [here's the feature request](https://github.com/appwrite/appwrite/issues/2740) for adding support for OR queries. I suggest adding a  on the issue.